# Jquery how do we add custom attribute to <img>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just want to add custom attribute to `<img> tag` which is created inside Jquery plugin....

```
this._image = L.DomUtil.create('img', 'leaflet-image-layer custom_image_class');
```

Above line creates `<img>` tag with the class name

```
`leaflet-image-layer custom_image_class`
```

I was able to add `id` attribute by adding

```
this._image.id = "my_image_id";
```

result is shown as,

```
<img src="" class="leaflet-image-layer custom_image_class" id="my_image_id">
```

everything works fine till above....

But now i want to add custom attribute "my_image" so that result should look like....

```
<img src="" class="leaflet-image-layer custom_image_class" id="my_image_id" my_image = "something">
```

how do we achive this?

I have already tried with `attr` , but no luck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that inventing your own non-standard attributes (such as `my_image`) will mean that your HTML is invalid. Instead you should use `data-*` attributes. Try this:

```
this._image.dataset.my_image = "something";
```

Or if you want to use jQuery instead:

```
$(this.image).data('my_image', 'something');
```

Comment: awesome.. thats all i want ;)

Answer (score 1):

use jquery attr

```
    this._image = L.DomUtil.create('img', 'leaflet-image-layer custom_image_class');
        this._image.id = "my_image_id";
        $('#my_image_id').attr("my_image","something");  // add this line
```